# Best path based routing tool for Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a monolith split into Kubernetes services. They exist under the following paths

/blog
/wiki
/

"/" is the app itself.

What is the most common tool to use for routing based on paths to a Kubernetes service?

Comment: An API gateway like https://www.getambassador.io/ that integrates into k8s is probably your best bet.

Comment: An API gateway for routing? Sounds a bit off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of ingress controller that handles the routing to the corresponding services. I would advise you to check out [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/providers/kubernetes-ingress/#:%7E:text=The%20Kubernetes%20Ingress%20Controller.,by%20supporting%20the%20Ingress%20specification.), [nginx ingress  controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) or [Kubernetes Ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) in general.
Which is the best? Simple answer: It depends on your use case and with what tools you are already familiar with I would say. In some cloud/managed kubernetes offerings like Google or Azure Kubernetes Service you can make use of the native tooling of the platform which is usually the fastest way of realizing such routing. But for a price of course.

Comment: Like the look of Traefik. Haven't yet been able to work out if it supports routing with a default path rule. I think I can just use the priority to place more specific /blog etc paths at a higher priority and then fall into the / path after.

Comment: to be honest, when traefik switched its syntax from frontend/backend to middleware/services etc in version > 2 I was kinda lost. So most of my knowledge still refers to the "old" naming. But it definitively should be possible to listen to the default path "/" when the corresponding service is annotated correctly.